# What is this small plant with bunches of small white flowers that look like roses

Tags: identification, flowers, plant-care

I am in souther ontario and was told this is a perennial plant.

What are care instructions?

Here is a picture with my finger right next to a full sized flower: [image: Here is a picture with my finger right next to a full sized flower]

Comment: Can I ask what makes you think this plant is hardy? Did the seller verbally tell you that, or is there some kind of label?

Comment: The seller told me that it grows year long. It didn't have a label and this was the last plant of this kind at the garden center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure its a Campanula, probably Campanula Wonder White (also called White Wonder); as such, there's a paucity of information available with regard to hardiness. Usually, potted Campanulas sold in the houseplant section are not hardy outdoors unless you live somewhere with warm winters, and are sold as temporary visitors to display indoors.

If you want to try to grow it outside, it might survive or it might not. There's also a Campanula Wonder Blue; both seem to be versions of Campanula haylodgensis. There are care instructions in this link https://www.whiteflowerfarm.com/how-to-grow-campanula-white-wonder, but unfortunately, no image of the plant; an image of it can be found here http://www.bcf.com.tr/Cok-Yillik-Bitkiler/Campanula-x-haylodgensis-White-Wonder, though you will need to translate from Turkish to English if you want to read it.

Comment: That looks accurate! Thanks